# OAuth 2Client: Invalid token signature

Tags: google-oauth, backend

I wanted to handle my user auth by google.

```
async verify(token) {
try {
    
    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken:token,
      audience: '245409008225-isc00em81fk0vs423pm4jmgc2hcma5jj.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  });
  
  const payload = ticket.getPayload();
  
  return payload
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

this code works fine, only for first time to create user in DB. And i save this token to localstorage and retrieve it every time to validate that user is authentificated. Here is my code:

```
async isAuth(token) {
    if (!token) {
      false
    }
    const userData = tokenService.verify(token);
    const tokenFromDb = await tokenService.findToken(token);


    if (!userData || !tokenFromDb) {
      throw ApiError.UnAuthorizedError();
    }
  
    const user = await User.findOne({where: {email: userData.email}});
    await tokenService.saveToken(token);
    return true;
  }
```

I did google, and i supposed to define jwk key for google auth api? But I can't find real solution. So, hope you guys can help me. I never used before google auth. For now I have this solution by making request to this api https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=token and getting from there my user email

Comment: id tokens have a very limited life span there is no reason to store it

Comment: Yeah you're right, I dont need even to save token to validate, i can just everytime request new token from google api and validate whether its expired or not. But, the token has 1 hour expiration, user will need to resign-in every hour

Comment: Yes, This is the way of JavaScript authorization.   Login every hour